# Accessing session attributes in Thymeleaf templates

Tags: spring, session-variables, thymeleaf

I would like to know whether is it possile to retrieve the session object and access its attributes from a Thymeleaf template without any controller code.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In Thymeleaf, session object can be easily accessed in a template:

- with a `session` variable:

```
    ${session.foo} // Retrieves the session atttribute 'foo'
    ${session.size()}
    ${session.isEmpty()}
    ${session.containsKey('foo')}
```

- with a `#ctx` object:

```
    ${#ctx.httpSession}
```

Look at the Thymeleaf documentation for accessing different context objects: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#expression-basic-objects

Comment: hello, is it possible to access currently logged in user via this `session` object? mainly for use in a `th:if` statement, maybe like: `<div th:if="${session.user.username} == 'joe'"></div>`?

Comment: @Scaramouche you can but you have to put the bracelet after joe: th:if="${session.user.username == 'joe'}"

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it's working for me :

```
th:text="${session.user['tel']}"
```